# Why terminal becomes unresponsive after Parcel build?

Tags: command-line, parcel

I am following Parcel's "Building a web app with Parcel" to learn how to use it. The problem arises after I type in `npx parcel src/index.html`. The build runs fine and I can see the development server results just fine. The terminal becomes unresponsive afterwards. I can't type, quit, or anything. The only workaround is killing the terminal and restarting...which is very annoying. I've looked for answers, I've updated Node to the latest version, but to no avail. This doesn't happen when I use Webpack or any other time. Here is a screen shot just in case that helps. Could someone please help this unworthy noob out? [Screen shot of terminal and VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQV6I.jpg)

Comment: If you type Control+C does it bring the terminal prompt back (where you can type things)?

Comment: `npx parcel` starts a dev server, which lets you view your app and will restart when you make changes. That server will run until you exit (which you can do by typing Control+C).

Comment: To actually build the app you need to use `parcel build`. You can read about all of this here: https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/

Comment: @Cully That works!! Thank you so much!! I spent hours trying to figure this out. Do you know why control+c is required here?

Comment: Because the dev server is still running. You start it with `npx parcel` and it runs until you exit. Control+C is how you can exit any program you start in the terminal.

Comment: @Cully So much to learn. So little time.

Comment: I posted my comments as an answer. You can mark it as the answer and upvote if it works for you.

Comment: @Cully I marked it as the answer. It's very useful. Thank you for taking the time to help me out. It seems I don't have enough "points" to upvote your answer though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you just run `npx parcel`, it starts a development server that will continue to run until you exit. This development server will watch for changes that you make as you develop and will reload your project, so you don't need to restart/rebuild every time you make changes.

The reason you can't type anything into the terminal (or, at least, that the terminal doesn't respond when you do) is that the development server is still running in that terminal. You have to exit the development server before the terminal prompt will re-appear and you can use it as normal.

**To exit any program running in a terminal**, you can type `Control+C` (hold down the Control key and hit the "c" key). This works for any terminal program, not just `parcel`. This will exit the development server program and you'll get your terminal prompt back.

There are other things you can do with programs (or "jobs") in the terminal window. You can read more about them [here](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/understanding-the-job-control-commands-in-linux-bg-fg-and-ctrlz/) and [here](https://www.networkworld.com/article/3284105/linux-control-sequence-tricks.html).

But you should use the development server to your advantage. Keep it running while you work. If you need to use the terminal while it's running, just open up another terminal window.

When you finally want to build your app/site, run `parcel build` instead.

You can read more about all of this here: https://parceljs.org/getting-started/webapp/